# Is there a name for the spoken emphasis like "Cuh-lean" for the word "clean"

Tags: speech, emphasis

At 8:15 in this video. https://youtu.be/Sly2Ik216DU?t=491

Anna says "That was cuh-lean!" as an emphasis on the word "clean". I've noticed this a few times in the past. Another example is the "homeless hatchet guy" who said "suh-mash, suh-mash, suh-mash".

Is there a name for that type of emphasis?

Thanks

Comment: Note that this theatrical emphasis is often pretentious or mock-pretentious.

Comment: Frankly, I think you've asked a good question. I might have even said at some point, "Suh wheat" (a drawn-out sweet). Or how about "Puh leeze" (a drawn-out please). And so on.